# How to Loop Through Swift Image and Test Pixel RGB Value?

Tags: ios, swift, image, loops

I have just started trying to learn Swift this past week. I am trying to write code to loop through an image in Swift and compare each pixel value to see if it matches a range of colors (a range of RGB values).

The image I would want to use would be one displayed in a UI image that the user has selected from the photo library (I have this part of the code done). I found this code on stackoverflow for looking at a pixel and getting its R, G, and B value:

```
extension UIImage {
    func getPixelColor(pos: CGPoint) -> UIColor {

        let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage))
        let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(self.size.width) * Int(pos.y)) + Int(pos.x)) * 4

        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+1]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+2]) / CGFloat(255.0)
        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelInfo+3]) / CGFloat(255.0)

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }  
}
```

Could someone help me to write code that links this code to run on the photo the user selects and to loop through each pixel?

Comment: Alternatively, if someone could explain the above code perhaps I could figure it out from there! And to clarify I would like to take each pixel and get its R, G, B components (alpha not relevant)

Comment: I don't see whats hard to understand, just by looking at the function signature, you pass a point in your image, then you get a UIColor back. If you wanna loop through all your image, write a double for that goes through your width and height of your image.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Pochi. I have continued working on my problem and will make a new post to better explain my difficulties.